# How to fix casting error?

Tags: c#

When i complile the code

```
class customer
{
Order getOrder;
public IEnumerable<Order> MyOrders
{
    get { return getOrder; }
    set{getOrder=value;}
 }
}

class Order:IEnumerable<Order>
{
    string itemName;

    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { itemName = value; }
    }
    public IEnumerator<Order> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this.GetEnumerator();
    }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(  )     
  {                                            
      return this.GetEnumerator ();
  }
}
```

I receive 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Order'

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an `Order` class that is `IEnumerable<Order>`, that enables you to enumerate the class, but it doesn't create a collection that you can enumerate.

You probably just want to create a colleciton of Order items:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
```

If you want to create a class that is a collection of Order items you can simply inherit from a list:

```
public class OrderList : List<Order> {}
```

Then you create the list like this:

```
OrderList orders = new OrderList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get { return getOrder; }    
set{getOrder=value;}
```

value is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable', getOrder is of type Order. Both are in no way compatible. Maybe you want getOrder (unfortunate naming also) to be IEnumerable, too?

Moreover this looks VERY wrong

```
Order:IEnumerable<Order>
```

I guess it should be something like `IEnumerable<OrderItem>`

Comment: You're most likely correct - It makes much more sense for Order to be an enumeration of items.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you have Order implement IEnumerable, which is fairly strange.  You can make this work, but it's odd.  Normally, you wouldn't enumerate yourself.

The second problem are here:

```
public IEnumerator<Order> GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator)this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

You need to switch how you're implementing your enumerators.  `IEnumerator<T>` inherits `IEnumerator`, but you're treating it the other way around.  Switch the declarations:

```
public IEnumerator<Order> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return this; // You need to create an ACTUAL enumerator here!
}
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator(); // This can call the above, since IEnumerator<Order> is also IEnumerator
}
```

However, in the code you posted, you never actually implement GetEnumerator to return an enumerator.  There are many options for this, but you need to actually create an enumerator (or use "yield return" and let the compiler do it for you, which I did above).

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues.  Your property `MyOrders` has a return type of `IEnumerable<Order>`, when the field it returns is actually of type `Order`.

Also, I am not sure if I read this right - `Order` has a base class of type `IEnumerable<Order>` - doesn't this create some sort of endless loop?  An enumerable of type enumerable of type enumarable of type enumerable of type enumarable of type enumerable of type enumarable...

Comment: No, you can technically do this - it's just very, very wrong for many reasons ;)

Comment: All it means is that an order has a collection of "sub-orders", which might or might not be empty -- imagine that instead you had class TreeNode which implemented IEnumerable<TreeNode> for its children.  Of course, in this context, it's probably just a mistake, but there's nothing paradoxical about it.

Answer (score 0):

What is class Order ? Is it supposed to represent a single order, or a collection of orders? If it is the latter, derive from a built-in collection class that already has IEnumerable in it (like `List<>`) than rename it so that it's classname communicates that it is a collection (`Orders` or `OrderCollection`) and delete the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` implementations (They come for free by deriving from `List<>` ...

```
// inheriting from List<Order> means you get Enumerable for free
class Orders: List<Order> 
{    
    string itemName;    
    public string ItemName    
    {        
        get { return itemName; }        
        set { itemName = value; }    
    }
}
```

Regarding implicit casting, In your case you cannot cast because a collection is not the same type as the type of object which is ***in*** the collection.

But, in general, you cannot *implicitly* cast a more general type to a more specific type, because it might not be the more specific type.  If something cpmes in as an `Animal`, you cannot implicitly cast it to `Dog`, - it might be a `Cat`.  (The other way around is all right You can implicitly cast a `Dog` to an `Animal`)
If this was the problem, you would fix it by *explicitly* casting instead.